# Doctrine - Getting Data from Two Tables with One Query

Tags: join, doctrine

Please can someone help me with a basic Doctrine query?  I have just split a large Orders table into seperate 'Customers' and 'Orders' tables in mysql. I now have the two tables setup as such in my Codeigniter / Doctrine application:

```
<?php

class Orders extends Doctrine_Record {

public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('order_date', 'string', 10);
    $this->hasColumn('item_code', 'string', 10);
    $this->hasColumn('invoice_number', 'string', 11);
    $this->hasColumn('item_name', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('item_type', 'string', 15);
    $this->hasColumn('item_size', 'integer', 1);
    $this->hasColumn('item_price', 'integer', 3);
    $this->hasColumn('item_quantity', 'integer', 3);
    $this->hasColumn('item_total_price', 'integer', 5);
    $this->hasColumn('item_b_order', 'integer', 1);
    $this->hasColumn('order_total_items', 'integer', 5);
    $this->hasColumn('order_total', 'integer', 6);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_id', 'integer', 4);
    $this->hasColumn('hallmark', 'integer', 1);
}
public function setUp() {
    // setup the join with the Customers table, linking cust_id in this table with id in Customers table
    $this->hasOne('Customers', array(
        'local' => 'cust_id',
        'foreign' => 'id'
    ));
    $this->setTableName('orders');
}   
}
```

and

```
<?php

class Customers extends Doctrine_Record {

public function setTableDefinition() {
    $this->hasColumn('cust_name_one', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_name_two', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_address', 'string', 50);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_country', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_business', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_email', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('cust_phone', 'string', 30);
    $this->hasColumn('special_req', 'string', 200);
}

public function setUp() {
    $this->hasMany('Orders as Order', array(
        'local' => 'id',
        'foreign' => 'cust_id'
    ));

    $this->setTableName('customers');
}
}
```

The query before was this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('u.*')
    ->from('Orders u')
    ->groupBy('u.invoice_number');

            $orders = $q->fetchArray();
            $vars['orders'] = $orders;
```

Now I basically just want to say give me everything from the 'Orders' table where cust_id in the 'Orders' table matches the 'id' field in the 'Customers' table, and group by the 'invoice_number' field in the 'Orders' table.

I've searched the documentation but can't get anything to work.  Any help very very much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I completely did understand your problem. But, if I did, just try the following:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->select('o.*, c.*')
    ->from('Orders o')
    ->innerJoin('o.Customers c')
    ->groupBy('o.invoice_number');
```

(Note that I switched `u` to `o`.)